# How to generate css radial gradient with fully transparent edge at the end

Tags: html, css

I'm building this complex button. For which I require a radial gradient. It should start as solid white in the center and should transition to blue color with complete zero transparency. I tried below but I can still see solid edges. I played around with farthest-side and corner with percentage but not able to get it right.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #7da9ff;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1320px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 240px;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn::before {
  z-index: -5;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a5b7ff, #4469ff);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -6px 2px #2650f9, inset 0 -8px #0931d7;
}

.btn span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 28px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn span::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 28px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)
  );
}

.btn,
.btn::after,
.btn::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 28px;
}

.btn::after,
.btn::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.btn::after {
  box-shadow: 0 9px 20px rgba(43, 58, 171, 0.2),
    0 37px 37px rgba(43, 58, 171, 0.17), 0 84px 50px rgba(43, 58, 171, 0.1),
    0 149px 59px rgba(43, 58, 171, 0.03);
  border: none;
  background-image: conic-gradient(
    #a5b7ff,
    #718cfa 135deg,
    #a6b8ff 180deg,
    #7d97ff 225deg,
    #466aff
  );
  z-index: -10;
  transform: translateY(12px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- Google fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Custom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css" />
    <title>Awesome Button</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <button class="btn">
        <span> Hello</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with an `ellipse` of a `radial-gradient` on all the four sides of the object to make it square, like so:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #7da9ff;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1320px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 240px;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn::before {
  z-index: -5;
  /* new code from here */
  background-image: 
  radial-gradient(ellipse at top, blue, transparent), 
  radial-gradient(ellipse at right, blue, transparent),
  radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, blue, transparent),
  radial-gradient(ellipse at left, blue, transparent);
  /* new code ends here */
  box-shadow: inset 0 -6px 2px #2650f9, inset 0 -8px #0931d7;
}

.btn span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 28px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn span::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 28px;
  background-image: radial-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}

.btn,
.btn::after,
.btn::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 28px;
}

.btn::after,
.btn::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.btn::after {
  box-shadow: 0 9px 20px rgba(43, 58, 171, 0.2), 0 37px 37px rgba(43, 58, 171, 0.17), 0 84px 50px rgba(43, 58, 171, 0.1), 0 149px 59px rgba(43, 58, 171, 0.03);
  border: none;
  background-image: conic-gradient( #a5b7ff, #718cfa 135deg, #a6b8ff 180deg, #7d97ff 225deg, #466aff);
  z-index: -10;
  transform: translateY(12px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!-- Google fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Custom css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css" />
  <title>Awesome Button</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <button class="btn">
        <span> Hello</span>
      </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But you can tweak around to your own liking.